# Click action doesn't work with dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog

I have problem with dialog and click action.

```
$("a[data-file]").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    getXML($(this).attr('data-file'));
});
```

This code works correctly with constant anchors but doesn't works with anchors in jQuery dialog. I have tried also:

```
$("document").on( "click", "a[data-file]", function() {
    e.preventDefault();
    getXML($(this).attr('data-file'));
});
```

But it doesn't work. How I should resolve this issue?

Comment: use $(this).data('file') instead of $(this).attr('data-file').

Answer (score 1):

You have wrapped `document` in quotes, which looks for element with tagname document. which do not exists.

You need to use `document` object here while using event delegation:

```
$(document).on( "click", "a[data-file]", function() {
    e.preventDefault();
    getXML($(this).attr('data-file'));
});
```

Comment: Unfortunelly it still doesn;t work :/ Jquery doesn't see these elements.

Comment: @RubenLech: can you reproduce the problem in fiddle.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/db5SX/6081/    The problem exist when you try click on link in dialog. When you click on link outside dialog, function work correctly.

Comment: @RubenLech: you have not used the solution i provided yet.